# How FIX choosing your permalink structure on WordPress for IIS server on Azure

Tags: wordpress, azure, iis

Need your help.
There is one IIS server in Azure.
It contains the Website and the Angular SPA application.
I need to install in a separate directory WordPress blog.
Blog unfolded.
But there was a problem with Choosing your permalink structure.

I have an error:
403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
Credentials that you are supplied with.

I have two web.config files
1. ROOT web.config

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
        <location path=".">
            <system.webServer>
                <security>
                    <authentication>
                        <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" />
                    </authentication>
                </security>
                <rewrite>
                    <rules>
                        <clear />
                        <rule name="Redirect http to https" stopProcessing="true">
                            <match url=".*" />
                            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                            </conditions>
                            <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" />
                        </rule>
                        <rule name="login redirect" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
                            <match url="^login" />
                            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
                            <action type="Redirect" url="ANGULAR-SPA-DIR/login" />
                        </rule>
                        <rule name="AngularJS Routes" stopProcessing="true">
                            <match url=".*" />
                            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                                <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="/ROOT-DIR/" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />
                                <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="/ANGULAR-SPA-DIR/" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />
                                <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="/TEST/" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />
                            </conditions>
                            <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
                        </rule>
                        <rule name="AngularJS Routes1" stopProcessing="true">
                            <match url="^ANGULAR-SPA-DIR/" />
                            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                            </conditions>
                            <action type="Rewrite" url="/ANGULAR-SPA-DIR/index.html" />
                        </rule>
                        <rule name="AngularJS Routes2" stopProcessing="true">
                            <match url="^TEST/" />
                            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                            </conditions>
                            <action type="Rewrite" url="/TEST/index.html" />
                        </rule>
                        <rule name="WordPress Blog" stopProcessing="true">
                            <match url="blog/.*" />
                            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true">
                                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" />
                                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" />
                            </conditions>
                            <action type="None" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
                        </rule>
                    </rules>
                </rewrite>
                <caching>
                    <profiles>
                        <add extension=".css" policy="CacheForTimePeriod" kernelCachePolicy="DontCache" duration="00:30:00" />
                        <add extension=".svg" policy="CacheForTimePeriod" kernelCachePolicy="DontCache" duration="01:00:00" />
                        <add extension=".jpg" policy="CacheForTimePeriod" kernelCachePolicy="DontCache" duration="01:00:00" />
                        <add extension=".js" policy="CacheForTimePeriod" kernelCachePolicy="DontCache" duration="00:30:00" />
                        <add extension=".woff2" policy="CacheForTimePeriod" kernelCachePolicy="DontCache" duration="24.00:00:00" />
                    </profiles>
                </caching>
                <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
            </system.webServer>
        </location>
    </configuration>
```

2. Blog web.config

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <configuration>
      <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
          <rules><remove name="WordPress Blog"/>
                <rule name="WordPress: https://ROOT-URL/blog" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                    <match url="*"/>
                        <conditions>
                            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
                            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
                        </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php"/>
                </rule></rules>
        </rewrite>
      </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

What can suggest experienced friends?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add srting to ROOT web.config

```
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
...
<add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="/blog/" />
</conditions>
```

After that, they "Choosing your permalink structure" work correctly

Comment: Add srting to ROOT web.config


<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
...
<add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="/blog/" />
</conditions>

After that, they "Choosing your permalink structure" work correctly